# Rails field validation not working as expected

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, validation

I have a users table with a row called screen_name which is a string.

Among other constraints the screen name should not contain characters like . , & % @ etc.
To this end I constructed following validator:

```
validates :screen_name, presence: true,
          length: { maximum: 15 },
          uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false },
          format: { with: /\w+/ }
```

When I then enter a screen name like foo.bar it was happily accepted and stored in the database.

What am I doing wrong?

```
# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: users
#
#  id              :integer          not null, primary key
#  name            :string(255)
#  email           :string(255)
#  created_at      :datetime         not null
#  updated_at      :datetime         not null
#  password_digest :string(255)
#  remember_token  :string(255)
#  admin           :boolean          default(FALSE)
#  screen_name     :string(255)    
#
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change your validation like this `/^\w*$/`

or

You can validate like this

```
validates_format_of :screen_name, :with => /^[A-Za-z0-9.&]*\z/
```

Comment: Thanks Raj, that worked. Can you tell me what the difference is between /\w+/ and /^\w*$/ 
Because when I test them in Rubular.com I see no difference.

Comment: @MPL Hi say your thanks by accepting my answer, by clicking green write symbol